# Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, error-code, mysql-error-1062

I have a problem on this error message, when i try this:

```
INSERT INTO `PROGETTO`.`UFFICIO-INFORMAZIONI` (`ID`, `viale`, `num_civico`,  
`data_apertura`, `data_chiusura`, `orario_apertura`, `orario_chiusura`, 
`telefono`, `mail`, `web`, `Nome-paese`, `Comune`) 
VALUES (1, 'Viale Cogel ', '120', '2012-05-21', '2012-09-30', '08:00', '23:30',
'461801243', 'informazioni@bolzano.it', 'Bolzanoturismo.it', 'Bolzano', 'BZ')
```

***Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'***

I haven't auto_increment data, PLEASE HELP me!

This is the table related, **UFFICIO-INFORMAZIONI**

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PROGETTO`.`UFFICIO-INFORMAZIONI` (
  `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `viale` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `num_civico` VARCHAR(5) NULL ,
  `data_apertura` DATE NULL ,
  `data_chiusura` DATE NULL ,
  `orario_apertura` TIME NULL ,
  `orario_chiusura` TIME NULL ,
  `telefono` VARCHAR(15) NULL ,
  `mail` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  `web` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  `Nome-paese` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `Comune` CHAR(2) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
  INDEX `Nome_paese` (`Nome-paese` ASC) ,
  INDEX `Comune` (`Comune` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `Nome_paese`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Nome-paese` )
    REFERENCES `PROGETTO`.`PAESE` (`Nome-paese` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `Comune`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Comune` )
    REFERENCES `PROGETTO`.`PAESE` (`Comune` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

**INSERT INTO**

```
INSERT INTO `PROGETTO`.`UFFICIO-INFORMAZIONI` (`ID`, `viale`, `num_civico`, `data_apertura`, `data_chiusura`, `orario_apertura`, `orario_chiusura`, `telefono`, `mail`, `web`, `Nome-paese`, `Comune`) VALUES (1, 'Viale Cogel ', '120', '2012-05-21', '2012-09-30', '08:00', '23:30', '461801243', 'informazioni@bolzano.it', 'Bolzanoturismo.it', 'Bolzano', 'BZ');
    INSERT INTO `PROGETTO`.`UFFICIO-INFORMAZIONI` (`ID`, `viale`, `num_civico`, `data_apertura`, `data_chiusura`, `orario_apertura`, `orario_chiusura`, `telefono`, `mail`, `web`, `Nome-paese`, `Comune`) VALUES (2, 'Via Olmo', '45', '2012-05-01', '2012-09-30', '08:00', '23:30', '393495169301', 'informazioni@lech.it', 'Lechinformation.it', 'Lech', 'BZ');
    INSERT INTO `PROGETTO`.`UFFICIO-INFORMAZIONI` (`ID`, `viale`, `num_civico`, `data_apertura`, `data_chiusura`, `orario_apertura`, `orario_chiusura`, `telefono`, `mail`, `web`, `Nome-paese`, `Comune`) VALUES (3, 'Via Quercia', '37', '2012-05-11', '2012-09-30', '08:00', '23:30', '393381679321', 'info@trento.it', 'Trentoinformaiozni.it', 'Trento', 'TN');
    INSERT INTO `PROGETTO`.`UFFICIO-INFORMAZIONI` (`ID`, `viale`, `num_civico`, `data_apertura`, `data_chiusura`, `orario_apertura`, `orario_chiusura`, `telefono`, `mail`, `web`, `Nome-paese`, `Comune`) VALUES (4, 'Via Atene', '76', '2012-06-01', '2012-09-15', '08:00', '23:30', '39349361345', 'info@sanmartinodicastrozza.it', 'SanMartino.it', 'San Martino di Castrozza', 'TN');
    INSERT INTO `PROGETTO`.`UFFICIO-INFORMAZIONI` (`ID`, `viale`, `num_civico`, `data_apertura`, `data_chiusura`, `orario_apertura`, `orario_chiusura`, `telefono`, `mail`, `web`, `Nome-paese`, `Comune`) VALUES (5, 'Via Salice', '45', '2012-05-01', '2012-09-20', '08:00', '23:30', NULL, 'info@pejo.it', 'Pejoturismo.it', 'Pejo', 'TN');
    INSERT INTO `PROGETTO`.`UFFICIO-INFORMAZIONI` (`ID`, `viale`, `num_civico`, `data_apertura`, `data_chiusura`, `orario_apertura`, `orario_chiusura`, `telefono`, `mail`, `web`, `Nome-paese`, `Comune`) VALUES (6, 'Piazza Sempreverde', '34', '2012-05-15', '2012-09-15', '08:00', '23:30', '392516789', 'info@ortisei.it', 'Ortisei.it', 'Ortisei', 'BZ');
```

Comment: So, there's already a record in the table having `ID=1`.  Since `ID` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, there cannot be multiple records with the same value.  What would you like this operation to do?  Ignore the new insertion?  Update the existing record?  Replace the existing record?

Comment: Are you sure the errors refer to the primary field of this table? Sould it refer to other ID from other tables?

Comment: 0 14:55:20 INSERT INTO `PROGETTO`.`UFFICIO-INFORMAZIONI` (`ID`, `viale`, `num_civico`, `data_apertura`, `data_chiusura`, `orario_apertura`, `orario_chiusura`, `telefono`, `mail`, `web`, `Nome-paese`, `Comune`) VALUES (1, 'Viale Cogel ', '120', '2012-05-21', '2012-09-30', '08:00', '23:30', '461801243', 'informazioni@bolzano.it', 'Bolzanoturismo.it', 'Bolzano', 'BZ') Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Probably you have an issue with foreign keys, I'm trying to replicate your problem with [sql fiddle] (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6fb9) but without success. Could you give as the complete db schema?

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60796322/ultimateProgetto.sql

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The <strike>main</strike> reason why the error has been generated is because there is already an existing value of `1` for the column `ID` in which you define it as `PRIMARY KEY` (*values are unique*) in the table you are inserting.

Why not set the column `ID` as `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PROGETTO`.`UFFICIO-INFORMAZIONI` (
  `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `viale` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
   .....
```

and when you are inserting record, you can now skip the column `ID`

```
INSERT INTO `PROGETTO`.`UFFICIO-INFORMAZIONI` (`viale`, `num_civico`, ...) 
VALUES ('Viale Cogel ', '120', ...)
```

Comment: i've just added ALL my INSERT INTO ; there are no duplicated PK.. that's because i can't understand what happened

Comment: You might have run the inserts more than once.

Comment: I've droped the schema and re-created for the 2 time... i always got the same error, as shown above.
EDIT:: the auto_increment would be an option, but it would work also without it...

Comment: Are there maybe inserts in the script you use to recreate the table?

Comment: In the script, there is first the CREATE TABLE, then INSERT INTO. These are shown above, and there is not other query/record for that table (UFFICIO-INFORMAZIONI)

Comment: EHM... SOLVED: while i was editing the mysql file i've done a cut&paste over another INSERT INTO.... so yes obviously there were at least 2 ID with the same number. Anyway know i know of this auto_increment way, thanks you!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UrYLYV7WSHM In this video "Cust_ID" contains "wilson44" two times...

Answer (score 23):

If you are using **PHPMyAdmin**
You can be solved this issue by doing this:

> CAUTION: Don't use this solution if you want to maintain existing
>   records in your table.

**Step 1:** Select database export method to custom:

[image]

**Step 2:** Please make sure to check truncate table before insert in data creation options:

[image]

Now you are able to import this database successfully.

Comment: This is one of good and time saving solution when using phpmyadmin or terminal to import database from another.

Comment: When trying to create new indexes on a huge table, I've resorted to renaming, creating a new table from the old, adding my indexes and then inserting from the old table. Was getting duplicate primary key errors even on the empty new table. Truncating it before copying data fixed this.

Answer (score 13):

If you have a new database and you make a fresh clean import, the problem may come from inserting data that contains a '0' incrementation and this would transform to '1' with `AUTO_INCREMENT` and cause this error.

My solution was to use in the sql import file.

```
SET SESSION sql_mode='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are trying to populate a table from a SQL dump, make sure that the table listed in the "INSERT INTO" statements of the dump is the same one you are trying to populate. Opening "MyTable" and importing with a SQL dump will throw exactly that kind of error if the dump is trying to put entries into "MyOtherTable", which may already have entries.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is related with your file - you are trying to create a DB using a copy - at the top of your file you will find something like this:

**CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `*THE_NAME_OF_YOUR_DB*` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci;
USE `*THE_NAME_OF_YOUR_DB*`;**

and I'm sure that you already have a DB with this name - IN THE SAME SERVER - please check. Just change the name OR ERASE THIS LINE!

Answer (score 3):

Also check your triggers.

Encountered this with a history table trigger which tried to insert the main table `id` into the history table `id` instead of the correct `hist-table`.`source_id` column.

The update statement did not touch the `id` column at all so took some time to find:

```
UPDATE source_table SET status = 0;
```

The trigger tried to do something similar to this:

```
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `history_table` (`action`,`id`,`status`,`time_created`)
    VALUES('update', NEW.id, NEW.status, NEW.time_created);
END;
```

Was corrected to something like this:

```
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `history_table` (`action`,`source_id`,`status`,`time_created`)
    VALUES('update', NEW.id, NEW.status, NEW.time_created);
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

When I get this kind of error I had to update the data type by a notch. For Example, if I have it as "tiny int" change it to "small int"
~ Nita

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same issue but here it seemed to come from the fact that I declared the ID-column to be UNsigned and that in combination with an ID-value of '0' (zero) caused the import to fail...

So by changing the value of every ID (PK-column) that I'd declared '0' and every corresponding FK to the new value, my issue was solved.

Answer (score -1):

### Using MySQL Workbench Import/Export

I got the same error as op when using MySQL Workbench Data Export. I was manually moving specific tables from one local device to another; both devices having MySQLWB.

**FAILED: data-only export**

On import, I got erors like:
`ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 83: Duplicate entry '' for key...`

**WORKED: structure-and-data export**

No other changes; everything else stayed the same.