# Spring-data-jpa OneToOne Unidirectional issue

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to have unidirectional OneToOne relationship b/w two classes "Restaurant" and "Manager". "Manager" is child class which has one attribute called restaurantId.
here is my code and problem is explained below it:

Restaurant.java:

```
    @Entity
    public class Restaurant implements Serializable{

         @Id
         private long id;


    //getters and setters}
```

RestaurantRepository.java

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface RestaurantRepository extends CrudRepository<Restaurant, Long> {
    List<Restaurant> findById(long id);
}
```

Manager.java:

```
@Entity
public class Manager implements Serializable {



    @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long id;
        @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,optional=false,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="restaurantId", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
        private Restaurant restaurantId;

        //getters and setters}
```

I am trying to test add method for Manager.java in below test class:

```
public class ManagerTest {

    private CrudRepository repository;
    @Test
    public void testAddManager() {
        AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");

        CrudRepository restaurantRepository = context.getBean(RestaurantRepository.class);

        Date date = new Date();
        Restaurant restaurant = (Restaurant) restaurantRepository.findOne(1L);
        repository = context.getBean(ManagerRepository.class);
        createManager("x","xx","xxxxxxxx","x","x","x","India","null","null", date, "jimish@auberginesolutions.com", restaurant);

        context.close();

    }

    private void createManager(String firstName, String lastName, String contactNo, String addrStreet,String addrCity, String addrState, String addrCountry, String addrLat, String addrLong, Date birthDate, String email, Restaurant restaurant){
        Manager manager = new Manager(firstName, lastName, contactNo, addrStreet, addrCity, addrState, addrCountry, addrLat, addrLong, birthDate, email);
        manager.setRestaurantId(restaurant);
        repository.save(manager);

    }
}
```

With above code I am expecting a new entry in Manager table, but It is trying to make entry in Restaurant Table.

here is console error in eclipse:

```
    Hibernate: insert into Restaurant (addrCity, addrCountry, addrLat, addrLong, addrState, addrStreet, contactNo, maxCapacity, name, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Sep 16, 2014 2:24:20 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
Sep 16, 2014 2:24:20 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
Sep 16, 2014 2:24:20 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
```

please help me out here. Any suggestion would be great.:)

Comment: How do you handle transactions? .. i think that resturant is detached when you save Manager and CASCADE.ALL persist again Resturat that have ID = 1 "Duplicate primary key". Can you add your configuration? .. one possible test is add on resturant entity @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO), if persist another one is as i say

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying to add an entry with an already existing id

Either you forgot to AUTO_INCREMENT the id or you picked an invalid (already existing) id for your manager/restaurant.

You may find more details there
[Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14628269/3816698)

Comment: I think the issue here is that he is specifying a unidirectional OneToOne link from Manager to Restaurant and then trying to save the Manager object. The Restaurant object that he is linking to manager object already exists in the Db. So, when you try to create the Manager record, it should not try to again save the Restaurant entry. How to prevent the saving of Restaurant entry?